# how to ensure NULL terminating strings for I/O to sockets c programming

Tags: c, string, multithreading, socket.io, c-strings

I am trying to get a server and client to communicate. The client has two threads for one for writing to the socket and one for reading from the socket.

initially the server outputs the initial greeting and gives the client some options. the client reads this just fine. But as soon as the client writes to the socket and then tries to read from the socket the userOut while loop keeps printing and begins mixing up the prompt in an endless loop.

I believe this is happening because I am not correctly handling strings and they are not NULL terminating so the client just keeps reading.

Is there a safe, and intuitive way to guarantee that ever string I read and write is a 256 byte NULL terminated string? (I don't care if it gets chopped off)

here are the two threads on the client side

```
/*
 *serverOut gets server output and prints to client.
 */
void* serverOut(void* serverName)
{
    printf("Getting server output.\n");
    char* server = (char*) serverName;
    char bufferS[256];
    int bytesRead;

    while(keepRunning)
    {
        // zero out buffer
        bzero(bufferS, 256);

        sleep(2);
        bytesRead = read(sock, bufferS, sizeof(bufferS));       
        if (bytesRead <= 0)
            error("ERROR read failed");

        printf("%s\n", bufferS);
    }

    printf("serverOut ending");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

/*
 *userOut gets user input and writes to server.
 *If user types 'exit', then they are disconnected.
 */
void* userOut(void* ignore)
{
    printf("Sending user input.\n");
    char bufferU[256];
    int bytesWritten;
    sleep(3);

    while(keepRunning)
    {
        // zero out buffer
        bzero(bufferU, 256);

        sleep(2);
        scanf(" %256s", bufferU);

        bytesWritten = write(sock, bufferU, strlen(bufferU) + 1);
        if (bytesWritten <= 0)
            error("ERROR read failed");

        if(strcmp(bufferU, "exit") == 0)
        {
            keepRunning = 0;
            printf("Disconnecting from the server.\n");
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    printf("userOut ending");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

and here is the thread that manages each client on the server side

```
/*
 * prompt function writes bank prompt to a given socket
 *
 * reciieves a socket descriptor as an int
 *
 * does not return anything
 */
void prompt(int sock)
{
    char *message, *opt1, *opt2, *opt3, *opt4, *opt5, *opt6, *opt7;

    // initialize options
    opt1 = "OPEN accountname\n";        // opens new account unless MAX_ACCOUNTS/_NAME is exceeded or accountName already exists
    opt2 = "START accountname\n";       // starts customer session 
    opt3 = "CREDIT amount\n";           // adds amount to account balance (only valid in customer session)
    opt4 = "DEBIT amount\n";            // subtracts amount from account balance (only valid in customer session)
    opt5 = "BALANCE\n";                 // returns current account balance (only valid in customer session)
    opt6 = "FINISH\n";                  // ends customer session (only valid in customer session)
    opt7 = "EXIT\n";                    // disconnets client from server
    message = "Here are your options:\n\n";

    // display options
    write(sock, message, strlen(message));
    write(sock, opt1, strlen(opt1));
    write(sock, opt2, strlen(opt2));
    write(sock, opt3, strlen(opt3));
    write(sock, opt4, strlen(opt4));
    write(sock, opt5, strlen(opt5));
    write(sock, opt6, strlen(opt6));
    write(sock, opt7, strlen(opt7) + 1);

    return;
}

/*
 * clientServerThread interacts with each client creating a bank client interface
 *
 * requires a socket descriptor as an arg to interact with client
 *
 * thread does not return exits when client decides
 */
void *clientServerThread(void *socket_desc)
{
    int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;
    int bytesRead;
    int exitFlag = 0;
    char *message;
    char *accountInSession;
    int accountInSessionNum = MAX_ACCOUNTS + 5;
    char acName[MAX_ACCOUNT_NAME];
    char buffer[MAX_ACCOUNT_NAME + 6];
    char optionBuffer[MAX_ACCOUNT_NAME + 6];
    bzero(buffer, MAX_ACCOUNT_NAME + 6);
    bzero(optionBuffer, MAX_ACCOUNT_NAME + 6);
    //bzero(message, 256);

    // great the new client and prompt them with the options
    printf(" Greeting the Customer");
    message = "Greetings! Welcome to Riordan&Hess bank how may we help you?\n";
    bytesRead = write(sock, message, strlen(message));
    printf("wrote %d", bytesRead);
    prompt(sock);

    while(keepRunning)
    {
        // zero out buffer
        bzero(buffer, MAX_ACCOUNT_NAME + 6);

        // read client choice from socket
        bytesRead = read(sock, buffer, MAX_ACCOUNT_NAME + 5);
        if (bytesRead <= 0)
            error("ERROR read failed");

        printf("PAST READ");
        // convert user input to all lower case for comparison
        int i = 0;
        while (buffer[i])
        {
            buffer[i] = tolower(buffer[i]);
            i++;
        }

        // check if client chose opt1 OPEN
        bzero(optionBuffer, MAX_ACCOUNT_NAME + 6);
        strcpy(optionBuffer, "open");
        if ((strncmp(buffer, optionBuffer, 4)) == 0)
        {
            printf(" USER CHOSE OPEN");
            // check if MAX_ACCOUNTS is exceeded
            if (bank.total_accounts = MAX_ACCOUNTS)
            {
                i = 0;
                strncpy(acName, buffer+5, MAX_ACCOUNT_NAME);    

                // check if matching account name already exists
                for(i; i <= MAX_ACCOUNTS; i++)
                {   
                    int accountLen;
                    accountLen = sizeof(bank.accounts[i].accountName) - 5;

                    // if matching account name already exists ask client for new name
                    if (strncmp(bank.accounts[i].accountName, acName, MAX_ACCOUNT_NAME) == 0)       
                    {
                        message = "This account name is taken please try again\n\n";
                        write(sock, message, strlen(message));
                        prompt(sock);
                    }

                    // if there are no previous matches and an empty spot is found create account
                    else if (bank.accounts[i].exists == 0)
                    {
                        // set bank & account mutex
                        pthread_mutex_lock (&bank.bank_lock);
                        pthread_mutex_lock (&bank.accounts[i].account_lock);

                        // initialize account
                        bank.total_accounts++;
                        bank.accounts[i].exists = 1;
                        bank.accounts[i].balance = 0;
                        bank.accounts[i].session_flag = 1;

                        // create session
                        accountInSession = acName;
                        accountInSessionNum = i;
                        message = "Account created and session started\n\n";
                        printf("account made");
                        write(sock, message, strlen(message));

                        // unlock bank mutex
                        pthread_mutex_unlock (&bank.bank_lock);

                        prompt(sock);
                    }
                }
            }
            // inform client that MAX_ACCOUNTS was exceeded
            else
            {
                message = "We are sorry to inform you that all of our accounts are in use. Please come back and try later";
                write(sock, message, strlen(message) + 1);
            }
        }

        // check if client chose Start
        bzero(optionBuffer, MAX_ACCOUNT_NAME + 6);
        strcpy(optionBuffer, "start");
        if ((strncmp(buffer, optionBuffer, 5)) == 0)
        {   
            // check if client is already in session
            if(accountInSessionNum <= MAX_ACCOUNTS)
            {
                message = "You are already in an account session please exit and then try again";
                write(sock, message, strlen(message));
                bzero(message, 256);
                prompt(sock);
            }
            if (accountInSessionNum > MAX_ACCOUNTS)
            {
                // check if matching account name exists
                for(i; i <= MAX_ACCOUNTS; i++)
                {
                    int accountLen;

                    strncpy(acName, buffer+6, MAX_ACCOUNT_NAME);                            // store account name on stack

                    // if matching account exists try and begin a session
                    if (strncmp(bank.accounts[i].accountName, acName, MAX_ACCOUNT_NAME) == 0)       
                    {
                        message = "Account found ";
                        write(sock, message, strlen(message));

                        // if the account is not in session begin session
                        if(bank.accounts[i].session_flag == 0)
                        {
                            // lock account mutex and start session
                            pthread_mutex_lock (&bank.accounts[i].account_lock);
                            accountInSessionNum = i;
                            accountInSession = acName;
                            bank.accounts[i].session_flag = 1;

                            message = "Session started\n\n";
                            write(sock, message, strlen(message));
                        }
                        // if the account is in session infrom client and tell them to try again
                        else
                        {
                            message = "Account requested is already in session please try again later\n\n";
                            write(sock, message, strlen(message));
                        }
                        prompt(sock);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // tell client no matching account exists
                message = "No matching account exists";
                write(sock, message, strlen(message));
                prompt(sock);
            }
        }

        // client has chosen exit disconnect
        bzero(optionBuffer, MAX_ACCOUNT_NAME + 6);
        strcpy(optionBuffer, "exit");
        if ((strncmp(buffer, optionBuffer, 4)) == 0)
        {
            // change global variable to in form client session threads to shut down
            keepRunning = 0;

            // check if client is in session->disconnect
            if(accountInSessionNum <= MAX_ACCOUNTS)
            {
                bank.accounts[accountInSessionNum].session_flag = 0;
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&bank.accounts[accountInSessionNum].account_lock);
                accountInSession = NULL;
                accountInSessionNum = MAX_ACCOUNTS + 5;
            }               
        }

        // client has chosen credit add to balance
        bzero(optionBuffer, MAX_ACCOUNT_NAME + 6);
        strcpy(optionBuffer, "credit");
        if ((strncmp(buffer, optionBuffer, 6)) == 0)
        {
            char *amount;
            float creditAmount;

            if (accountInSessionNum <= MAX_ACCOUNTS)
            {
                // copy amount to new variab;e
                strncpy(amount, buffer+6, 20);
                creditAmount = (float) atof(amount);

                // add amount to balance and inform client
                bank.accounts[accountInSessionNum].balance += creditAmount;
                message = "Credit succesful";
                write(sock, message, strlen(message));

                prompt(sock);
            }
            else
            {
                // tell client that they are not in a session
                message = "You are not currently in an account session please START";
                write(sock, message, strlen(message));
                prompt(sock);
            }
        }

        // client has chosen debit subtract from balance
        bzero(optionBuffer, MAX_ACCOUNT_NAME + 6);
        strcpy(optionBuffer, "debit");
        if ((strncmp(buffer, optionBuffer, 5)) == 0)
        {
            char *amount;
            float debitAmount;

            // check if client is in session
            if (accountInSessionNum <= MAX_ACCOUNTS)
            {
                strncpy(amount, buffer+6, 20);
                debitAmount = (float) atof(amount);

                // check if client's balance is greater than the sum requested
                if (bank.accounts[accountInSessionNum].balance > debitAmount)
                {
                    bank.accounts[accountInSessionNum].balance -= debitAmount;
                    message = "Debit succesful\n\n";
                    write(sock, message, strlen(message));
                }
                else
                {
                    message = "You do not have enough funds at this time\n\n";
                    write(sock, message, strlen(message));
                }
                prompt(sock);
            }
            else
            {
                // tell client that they are not in a session
                message = "You are not currently in an account session please START";
                write(sock, message, strlen(message));
                prompt(sock);
            }
        }

        // client has requested balance
        bzero(optionBuffer, MAX_ACCOUNT_NAME + 6);
        strcpy(optionBuffer, "balance");
        if ((strncmp(buffer, optionBuffer, 7)) == 0)
        {
            if((accountInSessionNum <= MAX_ACCOUNTS))
            {
                // tell client the balance of accountInSession
                sprintf(message, "Current Balance: %f", bank.accounts[accountInSessionNum].balance);
                write(sock, message, strlen(message));
                prompt(sock);
            }
            else
            {
                // tell client the must be in session
                message = "You are not currently in an account session please START";
                write(sock, message, strlen(message));
                prompt(sock);
            }
        }

        // client has chosen finish
        bzero(optionBuffer, MAX_ACCOUNT_NAME + 6);
        strcpy(optionBuffer, "finish");
        if ((strncmp(buffer, optionBuffer, 6)) == 0)
        {
            // if account in session end session
            if(accountInSessionNum <= MAX_ACCOUNTS)
            {
                // end session and inform user
                accountInSession = NULL;
                accountInSessionNum = MAX_ACCOUNTS + 5;
                message = "Session closed\n\n";
                write(sock, message, strlen(message) + 1);

                // Release mutex
                pthread_mutex_unlock (&bank.accounts[i].account_lock);
            }
            else
            {
                // tell client no matching account exists
                message = "You are not currently in an account session\n\n";
                write(sock, message, strlen(message));
                prompt(sock);
            }
        }
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Write code that writes a 256-byte string with a null termination. Write code that reads a 256-byte string with null termination. Only use those two functions to read and write on the connection. It really is that simple.

Comment: okay that is exactly what I want to know so what is that code?

Comment: @kevman Can you be specific about what you don't know how to do? Do you not know how to allocate a 256-byte buffer? Or how to put the string in it with nul termination? Or how to send that buffer? Or how to receive exactly 256 bytes? Or how to confirm that there's a nul terminator in the string you received? Where *exactly* are you getting stuck?